# How would the classes of regular, context-free, decidable, and Turing-recognizable languages relate to each other

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

I'm a bit confused as to how they relate to each other. I think I understand them individually but not sure how they would relate.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy#The_hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

Regular $\subseteq$ Context-free $\subseteq$ Decidable $\subseteq$ Turing-recognizable

Long answer: take a look at the computation models. You will see that each one is an extension of the one before it.